# I can't Use jquery in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

After I installed my jquery plugin http://farukat.es/journal/2011/02/514-new-creation-jquery-runloop-plugin in Joomla, I still can't call any function in there. It seems like there is nothing at all

In my Joomla template file index.php I included the called to GetDocument and AddScriptFunc for noConflicts() already. Do I have to open the javascript files in the plugin then Find + Replace All $ with jQuery to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to add $.noConflict(); from beginning of the jquery functions.
2. Sometimes jquery wont works so you have to rename all jquery to $.
3. Include noconflict document in that page.

Try these ways hope it will works...